# Is there an fzf for finding an open tab?

Tags: tabbed-user-interface, fzf

I would like to be able to open up

```
vim foo.md foo.css foo.html foo.ts
```

And either be able to run

```
:Tab md
```

or the like and jump to the `foo.md` tag. Is it possible to get this kind of functionality with Fzf. If I run `:Buffers` it does what I want, but it doesn't operate on tabs.

```
  [2]     src/app/foo.component.html                   
  [3]     src/app/foo.component.spec.ts                
> [4]     src/app/foo.component.ts                     
  [1] %   src/app/foo.component.css
```

Comment: Perhaps you need :Windows instead of :Buffers? Because output of that command has a tab column

Comment: @AnonymousLurker yes! That's what I want, can you make that an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need **:Windows** instead of **:Buffers** because output of that command has a tab column.